# Is it possible to convert a path to a stroke?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path, stroke, bezier-curve

What I'm doing is animating a stroke by first setting its `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`, and then animating its `stroke-dashoffset`, so that the stroke appears as if it is being drawn by an invisible hand in real time.

However, ***line animations*** require strokes because paths prevent `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` from having any noticeable effect.

I need a **stroke** with a width of exactly `1px` that is a **perfect** quarter-circle.

But, since I suck at creating perfectly curved strokes of a particular width, the only way I know how to achieve this is by creating a path from a circle object.

**Is it possible to convert a path to a stroke?**

**Is there a way to create a perfect, quarter-circle stroke that has a width of one pixel other than simply writing the code myself?**

Comment: Can you add an image? What is the shape you're trying to animate? I'm having a hard time understanding your quarter-circle stroke.

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, the Pattern along path will convert a path to be repeated or stretched along a path, effectively making it like a stroke. Documentation can be found here:

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html

You can also use this to make strokes have custom "cap" shapes (such as a quarter circle) if the usual "rounded" and "squared" options under the "Stroke Style" tab aren't good enough for you.

Sounds like your ultimate goal, however, is to just animate the svg path so that it looks like it is being drawn by an invisible hand. In that case, I'd recommend just drawing the path, and then using vivus.js to animate it. Documentation for vivus can be found here:

https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Comment: Because the `stroke-dasharray` is set to `'WIDTH-OF-ELEMENT'px`, it does not appear as a dotted line, but rather always as a solid line. In other words, you have a stroke of `10px`, but `5px` of that stroke is just empty space.

I'm struggling to comprehend the latter half of your comment.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer so hopefully it's clearer and more relevant. I've also added another piece of info that may help.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. First, in my initial response I meant `LENGTH-OF-STROKEpx`. Second, I'm implementing the SVG as an inline SVG in HTML format for use on the web. I'm animating it using JavaScript. All I need to know is how to make a perfect quarter-circle **stroke** with either the Bezier tool or by some other means.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial response, it's easy creating a quarter-circle **path**, but I need a **stroke** (not a path) so I'm able to animate it with JS.